# Rotate 2D grid of bits

Tags: matrix, rotation, bit

I got this 64-bit value that I represent as an 8x8 grid with top-right = LSB and bottom-left = MSB:

```
0x20E0 = [
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
]
```

I want to rotate it 90° left or right:

```
// Rotated right.
0x30101  = [
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
]
```

There seem to be a lot of ways of doing this, but most of them seem rather costly to do. I want to rotate it to simplify the logic of something else in my code, but if it slows down my code to the point of affecting performance I won't use it.

Are there sources I can look at? I've had a hard time finding information for my particular use-case. Probably using the wrong search words.

Comment: You need to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the matrix and flip each row. See how this is implemented in [numpy.rot90](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L158-L247)

Comment: "*if it slows down my code to the point of affecting performance ...*" It is impossible for us to tell, when our solutions will "*affect your performance*". Since your input is always 64 bit int, any sane solution presented here will have time complexity O(1). The actual time cost will depend on your processor architecture (and programming language). And the final impact on your application depends on the cost of everything else you are doing beside rotation. "*... I won't use it*" Do you really have a choice? If you can do without the rotation, why use it in the first place?

Comment: "*Are there sources I can look at?*" The go-to literature for bit-twiddling hacks is the book "*Hacker's delight*" by *Henry S. Warren, Jr*. If you do the matrix rotation by transposing the entire matrix, and then reversing each row individually, see Chapter 7 *Rearranging Bits and Bytes*; Section 7.1 *Reversing Bits And Bytes*; and Section 7.3 *Transposing A Bit Matrix*. BTW asking for literature is offtopic on stackoverflow.